# How to check if a variable contains a word in plain TeX?

Tags: conditionals, plain-tex

I have a variable that contains a long list of keywords, e.g.:

```
\keywords{computers, business, biology, fine art, literature, zoology}
```

I need to make an if-then statement that checks for the presence of a particular keyword, e.g.:

```
IF "zoology" IN keywords
THEN
    TRUE
ELSE
    FALSE
```

How can I check if a variable contains a particular keyword in plain TeX?

- I can change the format of `\keywords`, e.g. `\keywords{computers biology fine_art}`, if that will be easier to implement.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The following example uses package `kvsetkeys` to get a parser for lists with comma separated entries:

```
\input kvsetkeys.sty % parser for comma separated lists
\input ltxcmds.sty % helper macros

\catcode`\@=11 % \makeatletter
\newif\ifkey@found

% \testkeywordinlist{keyword}{keyword list}{true}{false}
\def\testkeywordinlist#1#2{%
  \edef\key@word{#1}%
  \edef\key@list{#2}%
  \key@foundfalse
  \expandafter\comma@parse\expandafter{\key@list}{%
    \ifx\comma@entry\key@word
      \key@foundtrue
      \comma@break
    \fi
    \ltx@gobble
  }%
  \ifkey@found
    \expandafter\ltx@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\ltx@secondoftwo
  \fi
}
\catcode`\@=12 % \makeatother

\def\keywords{computers, business, biology, fine art, literature, zoology}

\testkeywordinlist{zoology}{\keywords}{%
  \immediate\write16{* "zoology" found.}%
}{%
  \immediate\write16{* "zoology" not found.}%
}

\end
```

Result:

> - "zoology" found.

Answer (score 2):

You can use functional-style programming to build a fully-expandable version of [`map`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_(higher-order_function)) and string comparison.  This however requires e-TeX support.  Here I am using `\pdfstrcmp` to compare strings, so this solution is specific to pdfTeX.

```
\def\map#1#2{%
  \domap{#1}#2,\end}

\def\domap#1#2,#3\end{%
  #1{\strip#2\endstrip}%
  \ifx\end#3\end\else\domap{#1}#3\end\fi}

% skips leading spaces
\def\strip#1#2\endstrip{#1#2}

% predicate (pdfTeX specific)
\def\ifstrequal#1#2#3#4{\ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#1}{#4}=0 #2\else #3\fi}

% Check if the list contains something
\def\ifinlist#1#2#3#4{%
  \ifstrequal{found}{#3}{#4}{%
    \map{\ifstrequal{#1}{found}{}}{#2}%
  }%
}

% fully expand \map
\edef\found{%
  \map
    {\ifstrequal{zoology}{``zoology'' found}{}}% predicate with empty false branch
    {computers, business, biology, fine art, literature, zoology}%
}

\tt\meaning\found

% fully expand \ifinlist
\edef\found{%
  \ifinlist
    {zoology}%
    {computers, business, biology, fine art, literature, zoology}%
    {TRUE}%
    {FALSE}%
}

\tt\meaning\found

\bye
```

[image]